# combine dependent queries in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two separate queries.

1)

```
SELECT Email, UserId, FirstName, LastName FROM user WHERE 1;
```

2)

```
      SELECT COUNT(PostId) as userTextCount
        FROM posts 
  INNER JOIN user ON user.UserID =  posts.PostedAsId
       WHERE UserId='$uid'
         AND PostedAs='USER'
         AND PostType='text';
```

I want to combine these two queries in one. The problem is in the second query there is an variable callsed $uid which I will get after running the first query. Can we do in such a way that we don't need that variable and combine these two queries. Let me know if you need more clarification on it.

Thanks.

Comment: RTFM: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Comment: I know the use of join. But, second query will not run until i will get that $uid variable.

Comment: !?!? In which case it would seem that you do NOT know 'the use of join'

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Email, UserID, FirstName, LastName, count(*) as userTextCount
FROM user INNER JOIN posts ON posts.PostedAsId = user.UserID and PostedAs = 'USER'
  and PostType = 'text'
WHERE 1
GROUP BY Email, UserID, FirstName, LastName
```